# R, time series, looping in R

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series

I have a dataset with 79 items which has columns `id_number` and `id_sales` each id_number has 37 months of data.
Another dataset is id_no which has just the unique 79 id_numbers in the previous dataset mentioned, for each of whom i want to calculate mape from 3 different forecasting models(stored in a dataset named model) and all alpha values from 0 to 0.9(stored in a dataset named alpha_val)
.And lastly store the id_number, model name, alpha value and their corresponding mape values in a dataset(named mape_table_final) continuously with rbind. i am using the following code :

```
  for(k in 0:length(id_no))
{  
for(i in 0:length(model))
   {
    for(j in 0:length(alpha_val))
      {
        sales_idwise <- test_1[test_1$id_number== id_no[k],]
        sales_pre_ts<- ts(sales_idwise$id_sales, frequency = 12)
        sales_pre_ets <- ets(sales_pre_ts, model = model[i],alpha= alpha_val[j])
        sales_fc <- forecast.ets(sales_pre_ets,h=7)
        acc <- accuracy(sales_fc)
        mape_table <- data.frame("id_number"="09873564", "modelname" = "AAA", 
                 "alphavalue" = 0.1, "mapevalue" = acc[[5]]) # Number 5 indicates the position of MAPE in the accuracy list
        mape_table_final <- rbind(mape_table_final,mape_table)

       }

    }
}
```

As soon as i run the loop there is an error in the line in which my first time series is being created , i.e.

```
sales_pre_ts<- ts(sales_idwise$id_sales, frequency = 12)
```

which says :

> `'ts' object must have one or more observations`

can anyone please help me with this error or help modify the code? I'm struggling with this logic for a long time. the packages i am using are plyr, forecast, zoo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: R uses indexes starting at 1, not 0.

Comment: oh, my bad, thanks :)

Comment: i rectified that but another error is coming  over and over :                            Error in if (alpha < lower[1] | alpha > upper[1]) return(0): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed                                                                                 in this line-                                                                                   sales_pre_ets <- ets(sales_pre_ts, model = model[i],alpha= alpha_val[j])         could i get any help on this?

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Read it and figure out what is wrong.